# SharePoint 2013 - Library - Update an item of type Managed Metadata

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, managed-metadata, caml, library

I have a document Library.

It contains many columns out of which I want to update the value for managed metadata column.

Suppose, the Value which I want to update is "My Value" and this value "My Value", exists in term store and also in Taxonomy Hidden List.

Below is my code to update the value:

```
#CAML Query to get Item From Library and Update
        $spQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
        $spQuery.ViewFields  ="<FieldRef Name='My_x0020_Prod' />";
        $spQuery.ViewAttributes = "Scope='Recursive'";
        $spQuery.Query = "<Where>                                    
                                  <Eq>
                                    <FieldRef Name='Prod_x0020_ID' />
                                    <Value Type='Text'>" + $prodID  + "</Value>
                                 </Eq>                                         
                           </Where>"
        $col=$list.GetItems($spQuery) 
        foreach ($item in $col)  
        {  
           if($item.Count -gt 0)
            {

                $item["My_x0020_Prod"] = "My Value"
                $item.Update()

            } 
        }
```

This code doesnt update the MMD item in the library and throws an error:

> The given guid does not exist in the term store

Now, when I go back to the library and manually update the field for the MMD column, it works fine.

Programatically, this is not working and I think I am missing something.

Should I first get GUID from term store and then update the value in MMD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#Create a Taxonomy Session
 $TaxonomySession = Get-SPTaxonomySession -Site $web.Site
 $TermStore = $TaxonomySession.TermStores[$termStoreName]
 $TermGroup = $TermStore.Groups[$termGroupName]
 $TermSet = $TermGroup.TermSets[$termSetName]

 #Below line of code will get the name, GUID and other properties from TermStore
 $Term = $Termset.Terms[$MMDValueToUpdate]

#This is the Library Item OOTB ID of the item which you want to update
 $item = $list.GetItembyID($ItemID)
 if($item.Count -gt 0)
 {
 $MMSField = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField]$item.Fields[$FieldName]
 #If value exists in TermStore
 if($Term)
 {
 $MMSField.setFieldValue($item,$Term)
 $Item.SystemUpdate()
 Write-Host "Updated value as: " $Term.Name -backgroundcolo Green
 }
 else
{
Write-Host "Could not find termstore properties for : " $MMDValueToUpdate  -backgroundcolo Red
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you cannot update MMD field whose value is not present in termstore

You need to first get the term value which you will be updating

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy")
$site = Get-SPSite "http://site"
$session = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession($site)
$termStore = $session.TermStores["TermStore Name"]
$group = $termStore.Groups["Terms"]
$termSet = $group.TermSets["termset"]
$terms = $termSet.GetTerms(number of terms to be retrieved)
$term = $terms | ?{$_.Name -eq "your value"}
```

And then use $term to update in your code

```
 $termfield= [Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField]$List.Fields["My_x0020_Prod"]

foreach ($item in $col)  
    {  
       if($item.Count -gt 0)
        {

            $termfield.SetFieldValue($item, $term)
            $item.SystemUpdate()

        } 
    }
```

Comment: I do not want to update any values in termstore. I just want to update a value for MMD type of column(in a library). Even then, should I goto termstore and get the term value?

Comment: Yes, the above code does not update value in termstore but gets the value from term store amd then updates a mmd field

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am working on the suggested code. $term is coming as empty.  $_.Name is not a property which could be found. Any suggestions would be really helpful. Thanks Again !

Comment: Are you getting any results in the $terms object.Also check if you have given the correct termstore name,group name termset name etc..

Comment: Termstore Name, Group Name , Termset Name are correct. $termSet.GetTerms(1) does not return anything. I have mentioned (1) as I need only one term. Number of terms to be retrieved is 1 in my case. If I write $termSet.GetAllTerms() then all terms are returned. I need to search based on specific term.

Comment: Just noticed that $termSet.GetTerms(1) is getting the first term. The term which I am looking for might not be the first one. I think , I should not pass (1)

Comment: After getting all the terms try to filter it using the name

Comment: Now, am getting error **"Cannot call a method on null-valued expression"**  when I update the value  using this code: `$taxField = $item.Fields["My_x0020_Prod"] -as [Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField]                                                     
 $taxField.SetFieldValue($item,$term)
 $item.SystemUpdate()`

Comment: No luck yet, could you please let me know if the suggested code worked for you?

Comment: I posted the answer so that it will be useful for anyone who is facing issue in this scenario